# How NPM works on windows?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to know the process how `npm` works on windows I am facing problem with `npm` in my organization because it restricts users to modify or make `.cmd` files even with admin privileges. I was able to install Node before applying any policies of the organization. Is there any way I can modify the node installation to avoid using `.cmd` files?

Comment: You may find useful information in the doc: https://docs.npmjs.com/ Or  you could use something like [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) to have a dev env without any policies restriction (you're a local admin if I understood right, that should be enough for virtualization).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really since npm is just a bunch of node.js scripts, so at some point there is a need to call something like `node C:\Users\foo\....\npm\foo.js`. Without the `npm.cmd`, you lose the common command-line syntax and `npm.cmd` may do other things rather than only call `node` with the appropriate script.

Comment: Nothing really. You can of course always take the issue up with npm on their github issue tracker and see what they think though.

Answer (score 0):

For windows converting .cmd file to .bat does the same job. Before applying the policies I converted .cmd file to .bat extension have done no changes on npm.